# How to implement Third Party Javascript Library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, plugins, flippant

I have fairly good knowledge of web developement, but I've never implemented any third party Javascript plugins, so I'm a bit confused. Any help would be appreciated.

Okay, so lets say I want to use a plugin called flippant.
http://labs.mintchaos.com/flippant.js/

I got the CSS and JS File from the plugin, and put them in my  tag:

```
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Record.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flippant.css">

    <script src="Record.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="flippant.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

^That would be the flippant.js and the flippant.css

Now lets say I want to apply this plugin to flip a simple div container when I click on it.

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Now it gives you directions/code on the website linked above, so I'm not going to link it here. It's under the "Whys and Hows" subtitle.

So let's say I want to flip the div container when I click on it from the code above, how would I do it using this plugin?

Comment: Does the plugin's site not give you usage examples to follow? Strike that. yes it does give examples.. have you tried them?  What problems are you having?

Answer (score 1):

The library only provides the method, you still have to call it somewhere in your own code like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('container');
element.onclick = function() { // code from your library };
```

/Edit: regarding the question in the comment:

> Yeah, I did that, but it is still not working. Maybe I need to add the
>   flippant.min.js file that also came with it? I just added the JS and
>   CSS File from Flippant to the header. Although there doesn't look like
>   there is much in the flippant.min.js file.

The .min version of a file is the same code as the usual file, it's just a compressed version to save some bytes. I think the problem you had is [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript#Separation_of_behavior_from_markup).

You can either register an event handler on the html element itself like this:

```
<button onclick="flip()">Flip</button>
```

or in your JavaScript wrapped by this function:

```
window.onload = function () {

};
```

What probably happend is, that you tried to register an event on an element which wasn't rendered from the browser at the time of the script execution.

I tried it out myself and got this Code working:

```
window.onload = function () {
    function flip() {

        var front = document.getElementById('container')
        var back_content = "I'm the back!"; // Generate or pull any HTML you want for the back.
        var back;

        // when the correct action happens, call flip!
        back = flippant.flip(front, back_content)
        // this creates the back element, sizes it and flips it around.

        // call the close method on the back element when it's time to close.
        back.close();
    }

    document.getElementById('flip').onclick = flip;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The page you linked has this code example:

```
var front = document.getElementByID('flipthis');
var back_content = "<h1>I'm the back!</h1>"; // Generate or pull any HTML you want for the back.
var back;

// when the correct action happens, call flip!
back = flippant.flip(front, back_content);
// this creates the back element, sizes it and flips it around.

// invoke the close event on the back element when it's time to close.

// call the close method on the back element when it's time to close.
back.close();
```

You would implement something like this on some particular user event for your container object.

For example, you could put your version of that code in a function and then call that function on a click handler for a button:

```
function myFlip() {
    var container = document.getElementByID('container');
    var back_content = "<h1>I'm the back!</h1>"; // Generate or pull any HTML you want for the back.
    var back;

    // when the correct action happens, call flip!
    back = flippant.flip(container, back_content);
    // this creates the back element, sizes it and flips it around.

    // invoke the close event on the back element when it's time to close.

    // call the close method on the back element when it's time to close.
    back.close();
}

// assume you have a button with id="myButton"
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = myFlip;
```

Comment: Now would this go in the Record.js?

Comment: @BradleyMitchell - it can't go directly in `record.js` because you can't install the `onclick` handler until AFTER the page has loaded.  `record.js` is loaded in the `<head>` section which is BEFORE the page content has loaded.  You would put it in a new script that you included right before the `</body>` tag or you could move the `<script>` tag that pulls in `record.js` to that location and then put this script in `record.js`.

Comment: Yeah, I did that, but it is still not working. Maybe I need to add the flippant.min.js file that also came with it? I just added the JS and CSS File from Flippant to the header. Although there doesn't look like there is much in the flippant.min.js file.

Comment: @BradleyMitchell - you'd have to share a live link to your actual page so we could see why it isn't working.

Comment: @BradleyMitchell - how does one get to a working copy of the page from your link?

Comment: Not really possibly, I'm just making these files on my computer. I just sent you pictures of the source code.

Comment: @BradleyMitchell - it's not really possible for us to tell you where in your page you have errors or problems with something loading when we can't look at a working page.  If you don't have them on a web server of your own, then you could put them on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) where you can make a working example of your code and share it for exactly this kind of issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did.

I cloned the flippant.js repo from github and copied flippant.js into my app/assets/javascripts folder, and flippant.css into app/assets/stylesheets.

Notice at the bottom of the source for example page http://labs.mintchaos.com/flippant.js/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="example/browsery.js"></script>
```

You'll want to grab that bit of javascript and save it as browsery.js in your app/assets/javasccipts folder.  That has the Event Listener in it, so is probably the bit you were stumbling over. Obviously, you can rename this, customize it, etc.

I'm using Rails with HAML and pre-compiling assets.  In config/assets.rb you may need:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( flippant.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( flippant.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( browsery.js )
```

I'm including Bootstrap via a CDN in my views/layouts/application.html.haml file, so won't show that here.

Then finally, my view:

```
=stylesheet_link_tag "flippant"

    .container
    %h1 Notecard Flipper

    .row
      .col-xs-4
        %h2 Flip This!
        %p Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
        %p
          %a.btnflip.btn{:href => "#"} Modal &#187;
          %a.btnflip.btn.card{:href => "#"} Card &#187;
      .col-xs-4.flippant
        %h2 Flip This!
        %p Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
        %p
          %a.btnflip.btn{:href => "#"} Modal &#187;
          %a.btnflip.btn.card{:href => "#"} Card &#187;
      .col-xs-4
        %h2 Flip This!
        %p Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.
        %p
          %a.btnflip.btn{:href => "#"} Modal &#187;
          %a.btnflip.btn.card{:href => "#"} Card &#187;

    =javascript_include_tag "flippant"
    =javascript_include_tag "browsery"
```

You can use that same general approach with any plugin.  Hope that helps.